# Why doesn't this regex work with grep?

Tags: regex, grep

The input is a very basic html page with a git branch name and short commit hash, ex:

```
<p>master 72s6cg</p>
```

When I plug the page source into http://regexr.com/ I can target the commit hash with

```
[a-z0-9]*(?=<\/p>)
```

When I try to curl the page and pipe the output to grep all I get is a blank line.

```
foo=$(curl https://someurl.com/version | grep '[a-z0-9]*(?=</p>)')
echo $foo
```

Returns nothing

Comment: `grep` doesn't have lookaround support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
echo '<p>master 72s6cg</p>' | grep -Po '[a-z0-9]*(?=</p>)'
```

Output:

```
72s6cg
```